# How to get the corresponding TerminalNode of a token?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

```
export class TestContext extends ParserRuleContext {
    public _id1!: Token;
    public _id2!: Token;
    public ID(): TerminalNode[];
}
```

I use "labeled rule element" in my ANTLR4 grammar file:

```
(id1 = ID) "::" (id2 = ID)
```

How can I get the corresponding "ID" TerminalNode with token "_id1" or "_id2"?

I use "ctx._id1" to get the token, I want to get the corresponding "ID" TerminalNode with this token.

Comment: Unlike a [ParserRuleContext](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ParserRuleContext.html#getParent()), there is no "parent" link in a Token. That is because Antlr lexers work independently from the parser. You might be able to add the functionality by adding a parser listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular situation, the grammar rule will successfully match only expressions of the form `id1::id2`. Therefore, you already know that calling `ID()` will return a `TerminalNode` array with precisely two values: the first one, `ID()[0]` is the `TerminalNode` corresponding to `_id1` and `ID()[1]` is the `TerminalNode` corresponding to `_id2`.